# Django pre_save not saving changes

Tags: django

I need to modify some value before saving model:

```
@receiver( pre_save )
def model_pre_save( sender, instance, *args, **kwargs ):
    print instance.path # prints "old_path"
    instance.path = some_path()
    print instance.path # prints "new_path"
```

But after save `instance.path` still equals `"old_path"`.

Comment: pre_save does not save anything. That's why it's called pre_save

Comment: I call model.save() at another place in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**pre_save** instance changes aren't passed through, you should use update_fields as per documentation

[pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#pre-save)